# The dog language BOW

Tags: sequences-and-series

In the dog language, called 'BOW' language,the alphabet consists of the letters B,O,W only.Independently of the choice of the BOW word of length 'n'((i.e) number of letters is 'n') from which to start,one can construct all the BOW words with length 'n' using repeatedly the following rules:

a)invert the order of the letters of the word.(i.e if BOWW is a word then if we imvert the order of letters we get WWOB)

b)replace two consecutive letters:

- BO with WW,
- OW with BB,
- WB with OO,
- BB with OW,
- OO with WB.

Given that   BBOWOBOWWOBOWWWOBOWWWWOBB is a BOW word,does the BOW language have the word:

> BWOBWOBWOBWOBOWBOWBOWBOWB

Comment: Your thoughts? Your attempts? Do you think the answer is yes or no?

Comment: i think the answer is 'no'

Comment: Why do you think so? (To be explicit about what @5xum is asking you...)

Comment: It is just a wild guess

Comment: i have edited the question and hope it would be out of hold

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $N_O,N_B,N_W$ denote the number of $O$'s, $B$'s, and $W$'s in a word. You can check that the quantity ($2N_B+N_W$ mod $3$) is unchanged by the transformation rules. For instance, the rule $OW \to BB$ reduces $N_W$ by $1$ and increases $2N_B$ by $4$, which increases $2N_B+N_W$ by $3$.

Now just evaluate ($2N_B+N_W$ mod $3$) for the words $BBOWOBOWWOBOWWWOBOWWWWOBB$ and $BWOBWOBWOBWOBOWBOWBOWBOWB$. You will find that they differ. Therefore the second word can't be derived from the first word.

(I think that any expression of the form ($2N_X+N_Y$ mod $3$) will do here, but I haven't checked them all.)

Comment: i did not understand the answer canyou make it more elaborated

Comment: @lokeshsangabattula What is happening is the technique of finding an invariant. In this case he is using the remainder of $2N_B+N_W$ after division by $3$. The idea is that if the initial word has certain value of the invariant, and the rules for generating new words can only preserve the invariant, then all words generated would be forced to have the same value of the invariant. If the word you are testing has a different value of the invariant, then it cannot be generated from the initial word using the given rules.

Comment: @Ism: Thank you for that! You put it far better than I could have.

Comment: How did you get the idea of finding  2Nb+Nw

Comment: @lokeshsangabattula: Did you notice that all the transformation rules are of the form $XY \to ZZ$ or $ZZ\to XY$? That suggested an invariant, and because there are three letters in the alphabet, I immediately thought of $N_X+2N_Y+3N_Z$.

Comment: how did you guess Nx+2Ny+3Nz